# The Fashion Show

Tags: riddle

<drum roll>

> Ladies and gentlemen, welcome to the Stack Exchange Fashion Show! Tonight, we will show you the finest couture from all over the world.

The music starts, and the first models appear on the catwalk. The host of show did not lie; they are clad in the most wondrous outfits you have ever seen. Two by two, they make their rounds. As the models walk by, you get a strange feeling of recognition. **You have seen them before, but where?**

After the show, there's a big party, and the atmosphere and the drinks make you forget these thoughts for a while. However, when you arrived home, lying in your bed, you seem to be unable to catch sleep before you solve this problem. All you can remember is the following:

- The first two models were complete opposites.
- In the second pair, one of the models was almost forty times as big as the other one.
- Of the next pair, one emitted sound, and the other one light and warmth.
- The fourth pair were a light and a dark one.
- The next ones were almost twins, the host said something about one being twelve days older than the other.
- Pair number six were known for winning gold and bronze medals, respectively.
- The final ones had appropriate names for the objects they were presenting.

Based on these clues, can you figure out who the models in this show were?

HINT:

> This riddle is so easy, you won't need a hint. Just look around.

HINT for the final pair (which spoils the main clue):

> The names '011' and 'I Am Your Father' don't indicate that they are hats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are

> [Winter Bash 2016 hats!](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

The first two models were complete opposites.

> `Abominable` is for closing or deleting, `No Longer Grinchy` is for reopening or undeleting.

In the second pair, one of the models was almost forty times as big as the other one.

> `925` / `24` = 38.5 (nearly 40)

Of the next pair, one emitted sound, and the other one light and warmth.

> `Amped Up` is a boombox, `Fiery` references fire. (This could also be `Bûche de Noël`, a log fire, but this is used in another pair)

The fourth pair were a light and a dark one.

> `I Am Your Father` is Darth Vader, `Search You Must` is Yoda - figureheads of the darks and light side of the force respectively.

The next ones were almost twins, the host said something about one being twelve days older than the other.

> `Epiphany` (January 6th) is 12 days after `Bûche de Noël` (25th December).

Pair number six were known for winning gold and bronze medals, respectively.

> A gold medal is for first place, so `First Responder`, and bronze is for third place, so `Third Time's A Charm`

The final ones had appropriate names for the objects they were presenting.

> `Shapchat` and `Just Here For The Hat` contain the word "Hat" in their names.

Comment: OP said somewhere that there is a reason these are final for 'the final ones'. How does that fit with the answer? Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer :

> Stackexchange sites (still figuring out the pairs)

The final ones had appropriate names for the objects they were presenting.

> Stackoverflow, Superuser and Serverfault are the only sites with proper domain names rest all are sub domains of stackexchange.

Comment: Nice try, but not the answer I was looking for.